# Google Places: Error: statuscode=places_api_key_invalid resolution=null

Tags: android

Tengo un proyecto en Android que trabaja con Google Places. En la app tengo un botón que me debería llevar a la página de Google Places, pero se cierra sola y me da este error:

> E/Places: Invalid API key.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml. See
>   https://developers.google.com/places/android/start#api-key for more
>   details. E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=PlacePickerQuota
>   OperationException[Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID, resolution=null}]

Gracias.

Comment: Para poder utilizar la API de Google Places necesitas una clave, como bien indica tu error. Léete el siguiente enlace donde viene el procedimiento explicado: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key?hl=es

Comment: La tengo escrita en el manifest, pero sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: @PacoPepe el error es la posición en tu Manifest.xml en la que declaraste la API Key, recuerda que debe ser dentro de <application>, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

El error no indica que no has definido el `API KEY`, indica que lo has definido en una posición incorrecta dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml.`

El mismo mensaje de error indica:

> Revisar que
>
> ```
> <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API
> key"/>
> ```
>
> se encuentra en el elemento  del archivo 
>   `AndroidManifest.xml`. Ver
>   https://developers.google.com/places/android/start#api-key para mas
>   detalles.

Asegura qe definas el valor correctamente dentro de `<application>` y que tengas definida una API Key.

```
...
...
 <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="xxxxxx"/>

</application>
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.